# how to remove specific fields from List maps using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

how to remove specific fields from Array maps using dataweave without iterating the array

**Input:**

**`[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}]`**

I want to remove c and d fields from array(c and d values are dynamic)

**output:**

**`[{a:1,b:2},{a:5,b:6}]`**

How can we do it in data weave

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}] map 
$ - "c" - "d"
```

I used your input inline so it could run easily. When adding to a flow replace it with "payload".

Answer (score 0):

Combination of minus and map is the correct opproach. Map operator does iterate through array.